# if something == something show something and keep showing it

Tags: javascript, if-statement, p5.js

so when this is true i want to keep the images even when this turns false later

```
if (pose && label=="HowMuchCanYouSee"==true){
    
    let eyeR = pose.rightEye;
    let eyeL = pose.leftEye;
    let d = dist(eyeR.x, eyeR.y,eyeL.x, eyeL.y);
    
    
    //sharingan complete
    image(img1,pose.leftEye.x-d/2,pose.leftEye.y-d/2, d,d);
    image(img1,pose.rightEye.x-d/2,pose.rightEye.y-d/2, d,d);
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why the condition looks like this `label=="HowMuchCanYouSee"==true` and not just this `label=="HowMuchCanYouSee"`

Anyway you may add a new flag to the story starting with false that will be turned to true the first time your code it's hit, and after then, the condition will always pass because there's `flag===true` put in OR:

```
var flag = false;
if( flag === true || (pose && label=="HowMuchCanYouSee") ){
    flag = true;
    //the rest of your code
}
```

**Attention**: the flag var is declared global. That's not a good practice but it shows the concept.