# activate one thing deactivate the other if i say a certain word

Tags: javascript, if-statement, p5.js

I have a code that activates an image and leaves it activated but i want to change to other images if the parameters are met. i want to activate one thing and deactivate the other if i say  a certain word

My code: https://editor.p5js.org/perikleousd910/sketches/OI1glzfWS

```
let video;
let poseNet;
let pose;
let classifier;
let label = "listening";
let soundModelURL = "https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/xe3C8s4Co/model.json";
var flag = false;
var flag2 = false;
var flag3 = false;
let div = createDiv("div");

//var song = new Audio('sound/Itachi.mp3');

function preload() {
  img1 = loadImage("pics/Sharingan_Triple.png");
  img2 = loadImage("pics/Untitled-5.jpg");
  img3 = loadImage("pics/orochimaruright.png");
  img4 = loadImage("pics/orochimaruleft.png");
  //song = loadSound('sound/Itachi.mp3');
  classifier = ml5.soundClassifier(soundModelURL);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.hide();
  poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelLoaded);
  poseNet.on("pose", gotPoses);
  classifier.classify(gotResult);
}

function gotPoses(poses) {
  if (poses.length > 0) {
    pose = poses[0].pose;
  }
}

function modelLoaded() {
  console.log("poseNet ready");
}

function draw() {
  image(video, 0, 0);

  if (flag === true || (pose && label == "HowMuchCanYouSee")) {
    flag = true;

    let eyeR = pose.rightEye;
    let eyeL = pose.leftEye;
    let d = dist(eyeR.x, eyeR.y, eyeL.x, eyeL.y);

    //sharingan complete
    image(img1, pose.leftEye.x - d / 2, pose.leftEye.y - d / 2, d, d);
    image(img1, pose.rightEye.x - d / 2, pose.rightEye.y - d / 2, d, d);
  } else if (flag2 === true || (pose && label == "Orochimaru")) {
    flag2 = true;

    let eyeR = pose.rightEye;
    let eyeL = pose.leftEye;
    let d = dist(eyeR.x, eyeR.y, eyeL.x, eyeL.y);

    image(img4, pose.leftEye.x - d / 1.53, pose.leftEye.y - d / 1.5, (d * 3) / 2, (d * 3) / 2);
    image(img3, pose.rightEye.x - d / 1.2, pose.rightEye.y - d / 1.5, (d * 3) / 2, (d * 3) / 2);
  }

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  textSize(24);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(label, 118, 15);
}

function gotResult(error, results) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  label = results[0].label;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you might want something like this; the global variable `shownImageSet` is "held" to the last value if there is no pose and label.

There is no need for `flag`/`flag2` variables.

```
// ... initialization code elided ...
let shownImageSet = 0;

function drawImages() {
  // Select image set based on pose + label
  if (pose) {
    if (label == "HowMuchCanYouSee") {
      shownImageSet = 1;
    }
    if (label == "Orochimaru") {
      shownImageSet = 2;
    }
  }

  if (shownImageSet) {
    // Need to show something?
    const eyeR = pose.rightEye;
    const eyeL = pose.leftEye;
    const d = dist(eyeR.x, eyeR.y, eyeL.x, eyeL.y);
    if (shownImageSet == 1) {
      image(img1, eyeL.x - d / 2, eyeL.y - d / 2, d, d);
      image(img1, eyeR.x - d / 2, eyeR.y - d / 2, d, d);
    } else if (shownImageSet == 2) {
      image(img4, eyeL.x - d / 1.53, eyeL.y - d / 1.5, (d * 3) / 2, (d * 3) / 2);
      image(img3, eyeR.x - d / 1.2, eyeR.y - d / 1.5, (d * 3) / 2, (d * 3) / 2);
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  image(video, 0, 0);
  drawImages();
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  textSize(24);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(label, 118, 15);
}
```

Comment: The flag was there due to this being a follow-up to his previous question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794781/if-something-something-show-something-and-keep-showing-it

Comment: @Pellay Right. This has the same effect, but without having two flags.

Comment: it doesn't show the images now

Comment: @DimitrisPerikleous This of course only shows the concept of how you'd "hold" one of the two image sets to draw between frames. I don't know the rest of your code, I don't know how you've integrated this if "it doesn't show the images now".

Comment: https://editor.p5js.org/perikleousd910/sketches/OI1glzfWS.  this is my code

Comment: @AKX I know how your code works! :) I was just letting you know why those flags were there in the first place.

Comment: @DimitrisPerikleous You really should have supplied that with your original post!

Comment: @DimitrisPerikleous Thank you – I took the liberty of editing your code in to the original post.

Comment: @DimitrisPerikleous Please see my edit.

Comment: okay thnx man it works now you saved me <3